# Finding an object in a nested object: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an object array that I want to iterate through and return the nested object where the text property is equal to a given string parameter. 
For example, an object where the text property is "Book an Internal Interview". The object to find could be at any level of the hierarchy.

I was trying something like this, but it just allows me to look in a specific level:

```
var txt = "Book an Internal Interview";
var obj = items[0].items[0].items.find(o => o.text === txt);
```

So I tried a recursive solution:

```
var txt = "Book an Internal Interview";
var obj = customFilter(items, txt)

function customFilter(object, text) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty('text') && object["text"] == text)
    return object;

  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(object).length; i++) {
    if (typeof object[Object.keys(object)[i]] == "object") {
      var o = customFilter(object[Object.keys(object)[i]],text);
      if (o != null)
        return o;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

But I get an error:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

Here is what my object looks like in the console:

```
0:
    action: ""
    id: "1"
    items: Array(18)
            0:
                action: "http://localhost:8085/secure/contacts/create.aspx?CandidateID=2256"
                id: "20"
                label: "Convert to Contact"
                leaf: true
                level: 1
                parent: {id: "1", parentid: "-1", action: "", typeAction: "", text: "Workflow", …}
                parentid: "1"
                text: "Convert to Contact"
                typeAction: "url"
                uid: "20"

            1:
                action: "deleteCandidate(2256);"
                id: "2"
                label: "Delete"
                leaf: true
                level: 1
                parent: {id: "1", parentid: "-1", action: "", typeAction: "", text: "Workflow", …}
                parentid: "1"
                text: "Delete"
                typeAction: "method"
                uid: "2"

            2: {id: "21", parentid: "1", action: "ResetModal(); $('#TemplateDialog').dialog('open'); candidateID = 2256", typeAction: "method", text: "Generate Document", …}
            3:
                action: ""
                id: "15"
                items: Array(2)
                    0:
                        action: "bookClientInterviewSingleCandidate('46','2256')"
                        id: "16"
                        label: "Book a Client Interview"
                        leaf: true
                        level: 2
                        parent: {id: "15", parentid: "1", action: "", typeAction: "", text: "Interviews", …}
                        parentid: "15"
                        text: "Book a Client Interview"
                        typeAction: "method"
                        uid: "16"

                    1:
                        action: "bookClientInterviewInternalSingleCandidate('0','2256')"
                        id: "17"
                        label: "Book an Internal Interview"
                        leaf: true
                        level: 2
                        parent: {id: "15", parentid: "1", action: "", typeAction: "", text: "Interviews", …}
                        parentid: "15"
                        text: "Book an Internal Interview"
                        typeAction: "method"
                        uid: "17"
                label: "Interviews"
                level: 1
                parent: {id: "1", parentid: "-1", action: "", typeAction: "", text: "Workflow", …}
                parentid: "1"
                text: "Interviews"
                typeAction: ""
                uid: "15"

            4:
                action: "DisplayLinkToJobForCandidate('modalDisplay', '2256', 'Abigail Hotmail')"
                id: "19"
                label: "Link To Job"
                leaf: true
                level: 1
                parent: {id: "1", parentid: "-1", action: "", typeAction: "", text: "Workflow", …}
                parentid: "1"
                text: "Link To Job"
                typeAction: "method"
                uid: "19"

            5: {id: "18", parentid: "1", action: "loadMessageCenterSingleCandidate(2256)", typeAction: "method", text: "Send Email", …}
            6: {id: "14", parentid: "1", action: "submitCVSingleCandidate('46','2256')", typeAction: "method", text: "Submit CV", …}
            .............
```

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: **I need something more recursive** So write a recursive function. What part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: Can you use `JSON.stringify()` to post the object in a form that can be pasted into code for testing?

Comment: FYI, a simpler way to loop over object properties is with `for (var key in object)`

Comment: @trincot yes i invoking that method like that  var obj = customFilter(items, txt)

Comment: I am talking about the *recursive* call inside the function. Also be aware that `typeof null == "object"`, so if you have `null` values you would bump into an exception a bit later

Comment: @trincot getting the same error: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: My guess is that your object has self references. You can check what the result of `JSON.stringify(obj)` gives (before calling your function). I bet it is producing an error about that. Can you try?

Comment: @trincot yes i tried and i get the following error "Converting circular structure to JSON'

Comment: So that is the reason. You are looking into a structure that has loops, so your code will revisit the same path again and again until the stack is full.

Comment: right , yes it is a bit complex object. Any idea how i can iterate through it?

Comment: Thanks @trincot your contribution was great, hopefully the negative votes are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comments, your input object has circular references, meaning that a nested child object has a reference to one of its ancestors (probably the `parent` property is such a case). So your code will endlessly follow such a "loop" path.

You can protect your code from this, by keeping a `Set` of visited objects.

```
function customFilter(object, text, visited = new Set) {
  if (!object || visited.has(object)) return; // Do not go into loops and ignore nulls
  visited.add(object);
  if (object.hasOwnProperty('text') && object["text"] == text)
    return object;

  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(object).length; i++) {
    if (typeof object[Object.keys(object)[i]] == "object") {
      var o = customFilter(object[Object.keys(object)[i]], text, visited);
      if (o != null)
        return o;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

So:

- The function has an extra `Set` parameter. You don't need to specify it in the initial call, as by default it will be an empty Set, but the recursive call should pass the third argument
- It checks whether the object is already in the set. If so it exits.
- Otherwise it adds the object to the set

The `Set` will consume some memory (linear to the original input size). If you know that it is the `parent` property that is responsible for such back references, then you could also solve it by excluding that property from the loop.

Comment: man, you are great. it just worked great for any level of the hierarchy. Thanks. Hopefully the other guys remove the negative votes.